# Metal Residue On Dishes

Tags: cleaning, kitchen

I have a set of white dishes, plates, bowls etc. They are not stone or porcelain but I am not sure what they are. Every time a piece of silverware scratches against it it leaves a grey line which I have determined is metal residue. These markings will come off with baking soda and a lot of rubbing, but it's a lot of work and simply not worth it. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should use to clean metal residue on plates, bowls etc. is:

*whitening toothpaste.*

It would be easier to use than baking soda; even you can try to mix baking soda with toothpaste. To mention - toothpaste is not expensive. I using it for lot of purpose: to clean washing stand and drinking fountain, sometimes bathtub, to remove small scratches/dirt on car and also - for teeth.

Alternatively, you can try with alcohol vinegar. Other suggestion is to use [cream of tartar](http://www.thekitchn.com/the-best-way-to-remove-scuff-marks-from-white-dishes-225993), and also you can find more  [here](https://food-hacks.wonderhowto.com/how-to/secret-cleaning-scuff-marks-off-dishes-silverware-faster-why-works-0156242/).